# Prove (again?!) that a triangle whose vertex points with integer coordinates can't be equilateral?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I'm reading Courant's Calculus, there is the following exercise to prove. I've seen other questions with answers, but they (the answers) were somewhat different of mine. I want to know if my "proof" works.

> In an ordinary system of rectangular coordinates, the points for with both coordinates are integers are called lattice points. Prove that a triangle whose [*vertussies*](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1567682496877142/permalink/1792902761021780/) are lattice points cannot be equilateral.

I did this: Taking the following triangle:

$ \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad $  [image]

Then we must have:

$$m=2x \\ m=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Now,

$$m^2=4x^2 \\ m^2=x^2+y^2$$

As $\displaystyle x=\frac{m}{2}$, we have:

$$m^2=4x^2 \\ 3m^2=y^2$$

And:

$$y=\sqrt{3}m$$

Now suppose we take an integer $m_0>0$, $\displaystyle x=\frac{m_0}{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{3}m_0$. As $m_0$ is an integer, it can be uniquely factored in a product of primes $m_0=2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2}\dots p^{\alpha_n}$ with $\alpha_i\in \Bbb{N}$. Now:

$$y=\sqrt{3}(2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2}\dots p^{\alpha_n})=3^{\frac{1}{2}}(2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2}\dots p^{\alpha_n})=2^{\alpha_1}\cdot 3^{\alpha_2+\frac{1}{2}}\dots p^{\alpha_n}$$

Contradiction because $\alpha_2 + \frac{1}{2}\not\in \Bbb{N}$. With this, we actually took integers $\geq 2$, it remains to be proved that $m_0=1$ also won't provide an equilateral triangle, but this is trivial because:

$$y=\sqrt{3}\cdot 1= \sqrt{3}\not\in \Bbb{N}$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: No, it's not. You only proved it for the case where two of the  lattice point vertices have the same $y$-coordinate (i.e., they lie on a horizontal line).

Comment: Also, I'm sure you are allowed to assume without proof that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, so once you get $y=m\sqrt{3}$, you can just isolate $\sqrt{3}$ and you have an immediate contradiction. No need for all the prime factorization stuff.

Comment: If you know some field theory, you can simply show that a primitive cubic root does not lie in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\text{i})$ of Gaussian rational numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right trail, the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$ is crucial, here. If such a triangle were possible, we'd have two integer vectors $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ forming an angle of $60°$. That means that their scalar product would be $\cos 60°=1/2$ times the product of their lengths, and the area of the parallelogram formed by them would be $\sin 60°=\sqrt{3}/2$ times the product of their lengths. The squares of those equations would be $$(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2=\frac{1}{4}(x^2_1+x^2_2)(y^2_1+y^2_2)$$ and $$(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2=\frac{3}{4}(x^2_1+x^2_2)(y^2_1+y^2_2).$$ Dividing them gives $$\left(\frac{x_1y_2-x_2y_1}{x_1y_1+x_2y_2}\right)^2=3,$$ i.e. $3$ would be the square of a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

It's not restrictive to assume that one vertex is the origin, because a translation moving a lattice point to a lattice point also moves *all* lattice points to lattice points.

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ be the other two vertices; then the area of the triangle is
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left|
  \det\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}
\right|
$$

On the other hand, the area is also $\frac{1}{2}l^2\sin\frac{\pi}{3}$, where $l$ is the length of the sides and
$$
l^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2
$$
This implies
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\frac{|x_1y_2-x_2y_1|}{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}
$$
is a rational number.